# GoogleMaps API + SQL database + rendering points PHP

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, rendering

I am working on a project where users could fill a form to feed a SQL database and then I would render the inputs on a map.

I've already completed the form and the database part and most of the map. Based on the documentation from Google Maps API, I've been able to render a map with the points of my database so I know that the PHP script that "reads the database" is correct.

Now the issue I'm facing is that when I try to integrate the piece of code (the output coming from the database) within my other scripts (geolocation, styling of the map) it no longer work (the map is showing up but the not the points from the database, whereas if I try the html example from there https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#custom-icons I can see the points from my database.

```
<!-- 3) Map creation -->
        <script>

            var map;
              function initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                  zoom: 17,
                  styles: [{"stylers":[{"hue":"#16a085"},{"saturation":0}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"lightness":100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]}]
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemaps'),
                    mapOptions);

              // Try HTML5 geolocation
              if(navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                                   position.coords.longitude);

                  var contentString = '<div id="infowindow">Vous êtes ici :-)</div>'

                  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    map: map,
                    position: pos,
                    content: contentString
                  });

                  map.setCenter(pos);
                  map.setZoom(17);
                }, function() {
                  handleNoGeolocation(true);
                });

                // PHP file to render the data from sql
                  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
                    var xml = data.responseXML;
                    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
                    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
                      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
                      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
                      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: point,
                        icon: icon.icon
                      });
                      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
                    }
                });
                } 

                else {
                // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                handleNoGeolocation(false);
                }
                }

                function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
                  if (errorFlag) {
                    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
                  } else {
                    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
                  }

                  var options = {
                    map: map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
                    content: content
                  };

                  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
                  map.setCenter(options.position);
                }

                function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(html);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                  });
                }

                function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
                  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                      new XMLHttpRequest;

                  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (request.readyState == 4) {
                      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                      callback(request, request.status);
                    }
                  };

                  request.open('GET', url, true);
                  request.send(null);
                }

                function doNothing() {}


                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
```

Could you please let me know what's wrong with my script?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Check in browser console for error  ..

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message. I've checked the console and the only error message I can see are:    
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined
localhost/:136 Uncaught ReferenceError: infoWindow is not defined
maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/24/2/intl/fr_ALL/util.js:218 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Answer (score 0):

I get a javascript error with the posted code `Uncaught ReferenceError: customIcons is not defined`

If you don't need custom icons, remove the code that depends on them:

```
 // var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   map: map,
   position: point,
   // icon: icon.icon
 });
```

And the javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: infoWindow is not defined`

Javascript is case sensitive, infoWindow and infowindow are different things, you don't define the infoWindow variable that you pass into the call to `bindInfoWindow`.

```
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
```

should be:

```
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, html);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nregjn22/)

**code snippet:**

```js
 var map;

 function initialize() {
   var mapOptions = {
     zoom: 17,
     styles: [{
       "stylers": [{
         "hue": "#16a085"
       }, {
         "saturation": 0
       }]
     }, {
       "featureType": "road",
       "elementType": "geometry",
       "stylers": [{
         "lightness": 100
       }, {
         "visibility": "simplified"
       }]
     }, {
       "featureType": "road",
       "elementType": "labels",
       "stylers": [{
         "visibility": "off"
       }]
     }]
   };
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemaps'),
     mapOptions);

   // Try HTML5 geolocation
   /* if (navigator.geolocation) {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
       var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
         position.coords.longitude);
*/
   var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(42, -72);
   var contentString = '<div id="infowindow">Vous êtes ici :-)</div>'

   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     map: map,
     position: pos,
     content: contentString
   });

   map.setCenter(pos);
   map.setZoom(2);
   /*}, function() {
     handleNoGeolocation(true);
   }); */

   // PHP file to render the data from sql
   // downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
   var xml = parseXml(xmlData); // data.responseXML;
   var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
     var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
     var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
     var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
     var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
       parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
       parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
     var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
     // var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: map,
       position: point,
       // icon: icon.icon
     });
     bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, html);
   }
   // });
   /*    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
      }
      */
 }

 var xmlData = '<markers><marker name="Pan Africa Market" address="1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.608940" lng="-122.340141" type="restaurant" /><marker name="Buddha Thai &amp; Bar" address="2222 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613590" lng="-122.344391" type="bar" /><marker name="The Melting Pot" address="14 Mercer St, Seattle, WA" lat="47.624561" lng="-122.356445" type="restaurant" /><marker name="Ipanema Grill" address="1225 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.606365" lng="-122.337654" type="restaurant" /><marker name="Sake House" address="2230 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.612823" lng="-122.345673" type="bar" /><marker name="Crab Pot" address="1301 Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.605961" lng="-122.340363" type="restaurant" /><marker name="Mama&amp;apos;s Mexican Kitchen" address="2234 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613976" lng="-122.345467" type="bar" /><marker name="Wingdome" address="1416 E Olive Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.617214" lng="-122.326584" type="bar" /><marker name="Piroshky Piroshky" address="1908 Pike pl, Seattle, WA" lat="47.610126" lng="-122.342834" type="restaurant" /></markers>';

 function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
   if (errorFlag) {
     var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
   } else {
     var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
   }

   var options = {
     map: map,
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
     content: content
   };

   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
   map.setCenter(options.position);
 }

 function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infoWindow.setContent(html);
     infoWindow.open(map, marker);
   });
 }

 function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
   var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
     new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
     new XMLHttpRequest;

   request.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (request.readyState == 4) {
       request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
       callback(request, request.status);
     }
   };

   request.open('GET', url, true);
   request.send(null);
 }

 function doNothing() {}

 function parseXml(str) {
   if (window.ActiveXObject) {
     var doc = new ActiveXObject('MicrosoftXMLDOM');
     doc.loadXML(str);
     return doc;
   } else if (window.DOMParser) {
     return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
   }
 };

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googlemaps {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="googlemaps"></div>
```